# &:focus on input wont change element

Tags: html, css, focus

I am trying make a button appear after typing in my `input` tag. Currently I set my button to `display: none` and when I focus on the input field, it should change my `display: inline-block` which should make it reappear. What am I doing wrong?

html

```
            <h1 className='title-caption'>Get started today!</h1>
                <div className='email-newsletter-container'>
                    <p className='sign-up-caption'>
                        Sign up for our newletter for more information
                    </p>
                    <input
                        className='email-input'
                        placeholder='Enter email address'
                    ></input>
                    <br />
                    <button className='submit-button' id='submit-button'>
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
```

css

```
    .email-input {
        margin-top: 20px;
        height: 40px;
        width: 400px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        position: relative;

        &:focus + .submit-button {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }

    .email-input:focus + .submit-button {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .submit-button {
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 20px;
        width: 90px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',
            'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 2px solid white;
        color: white;
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: just to make sure: you "CSS" code has to run through a preprocessor first. you did that, right?

Comment: @Sirko, sure he did not, these are all CSS selectors

Comment: Try the `~` selector instead of the `+` selector. `+` will select any element immidiately place after, while the `~` selects any element that is proceeded the element

Comment: @Simplicius Can you then please explain to me to which part of the CSS-standard this applies: `&:focus + .submit-button` as a nested selector.

Comment: @Sirko, here's some reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @Simplicius a) https://www.w3fools.com/ b) this does not say anything about nested selectors being admitted to the CSS standard. The syntax looks like LESS or SASS to me.

Comment: @skiro, No, Sass can't do anything that CSS can't, since it's a **pre**complier. Btw it's listed here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @Simplicius I know what that is, but the above code claims this is valid CSS, which (in my opinion) it is not. You need to run it through some precompiler before actually using it. The precompiler transpiles the added syntactic sugar to plain CSS. So you can use nested selectors in LESS/SASS, but you can not use them directly in CSS.

Comment: @Sirko, sorry, didn't get you. Yes the `&` selector is not valid CSS, but a Sass and Less selector. But he's also using the `+` wrong in this case, that's why the button doesn't get targeted.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, I am using SASS. Using `~` instead of `+` fixed the issue! thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
button {
  display: none;
}

input:focus ~ button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div></div>
<button>Button</button>
```

Use the `~` selector instead of the `+` selector. [Here](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/xxVjvKx)'s a little demonstration.

The `+` selector will only select the sibling immidiately placed after, while the `~` selector will select any sibling placed after, using the class selector we can then filter those.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try something like this
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqdnmgs0/1/)

CSS

```
.email-input {
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;

    &:focus + .submit-button {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

.email-input:focus + .submit-button {
    display: inline-block;
}

.submit-button {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 90px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',
        'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
 if (x.style.display === "block") {
 x.style.display = "none";
 } else {
 x.style.display = "block";
 }
 }
</script>
<h1 className='title-caption'>Get started today!</h1>
            <div className='email-newsletter-container'>
                <p className='sign-up-caption'>
                    Sign up for our newletter for more information
                </p>
                <input
                    className='email-input'
                    placeholder='Enter email address'
                    onfocus="myFunction()"
                    
                ></input>
                <br />
                <button style="display:none" className='submit' id="myDIV">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- `<input />` tag is self closed. It is incorrect in your syntax.
- `&:focus + .submit-button { display: inline-block; }` - it means that after input follows .submit-buton but in your html there is `<br/>` tag after input, so this will not work

Comment: ok I wrote in general about mistakes,  so is it bad ?